# Linking css file to html file

Tags: html

hi I am having a problem of lining my css file in my html file when I include the css file in a separate folder and link it to html by providing the directory and folder name it does not work but when I take the css file out of the folder and then link it it works then

Comment: share your code

Comment: show your directory of files and how you are including the CSS

Answer (score 0):

files inside folders can be tricky. Lets say you have the following.

folderA >>
   fileA.css

index.html

---

File A is inside of Folder A. To get to it, you would need to insert the following into your html code:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./folderA/fileA.css">`

You can change the file/folder names to suit your needs, as you have not specified the exact names.

Comment: /Users/saud/Desktop/Screenshot 2019-04-26 at 17.13.54.jpg